# An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Error Occured in _context.userAccount.ToList()

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 48.

OurDbContext.cs

```
public class OurDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public OurDbContext(DbContextOptions<OurDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<UserAccount> userAccount { get; set; }
    }
```

HomeController.cs

```
private OurDbContext _context;
public HomeController(OurDbContext context)
{
     _context = context;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
     return View(_context.userAccount.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do check the connection string in your config file and make sure that there is no special character that should be escaped, like any termination or any such character in your connection string.

Comment: var connection = "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=LoginDb;Integrated Security=True;";
services.AddDbContext<OurDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

Comment: Are you running this in visual studio or through IIS?

Comment: Yes, i m project running in visual studio 2015 community through IIS...

Comment: Using 'Dotnet Run' in command prompt there is no error successfully run but in through IIS occur error.

Comment: Running with IIS, make sure that data source is reachable. Instead of ".\\SQLExpress" try defining server name.